# reconhecimento de voz com Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação desktop, preciso usar reconhecimento de voz, mas todo material que eu acho é referente a versão 2 do Python.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso usando bibliotecas para Python 3?

Comment: Quais bibliotecas você está usando?

Comment: Tenta este modulo: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

Comment: eu usei esta mesmo

Comment: E qual foi a dificuldade de usar ele no Python 3? Conforme consta na documentação, o requerimento é "Python 2.6, 2.7, or 3.3+". Logo, deveria funcionar com Python 3 acima da versão 3.3... Forneça mais detalhes, senão você corre o risco de ter a sua pergunta fechada como não clara.